# is_dir function for FTP/FTPS connections

Tags: php, file-system, ftp

I'm implementing an `is_dir()` function to determine if a given item is a directory or a file for FTP/FTPS connections. Currently, I have two methods: one using PHP's FTP wrapper for the `is_dir()` function and another recommended in the help page for the `ftp_chdir()` function.

Here's the first one (protocol wrapper):

```
if ($items = ftp_nlist($this->attributes["link"], $path)) {
    $output = null;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (is_dir("ftp://{$this->attributes["user"]}:{$this->attributes["password"]}@{$this->attributes["host"]}/{$item}")) {
            $output[] = $item;
        }
    } 

    $output[] = sprintf("%5.4fs", (microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]));
    return $output;
}
```

Here's the second one (chdir implementation):

```
if ($items = ftp_nlist($this->attributes["link"], $path)) {
    $output = null;
    $current = ftp_pwd($this->attributes["link"]);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (@ftp_chdir($this->attributes["link"], $item)) {
            ftp_chdir($this->attributes["link"], $current);
            $output[] = $item;
        }
    }

    $output[] = sprintf("%5.4fs", (microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]));
    return $output;
}
```

The problem I find with these two implementations is they're quite slow (or, at least, I think they should be faster to be used within AJAX calls). Running these two functions and measuring their execution time with the last element in the returned array, these are their timed values (ran them 50 times to get an accurate enough time reading): 7.2312s for method A and 2.4534s for method B.

Which shows the `ftp_chdir()` implementation is almost 3x faster than using the FTP wrapper. Still... I have the feeling there may be room for improvement.

My development machine is Windows 7 x64 with Apache 2.4.4 (x86), PHP 5.4.13 (x86, thread-safe version) and MySQL 5.6.10 x64 (irrelevant in this case), always keeping up-to-date packages. The FTP server I ran these tests against is another Windows machine but a full-fledged production server (dedicated) on a data center.

Is there any other method to do the same but in a better (and/or faster) fashion?

Comment: Why do you iterate through all entries of the directory?

Comment: Because it's how the original `ftp_chdir()` implementation is done and, as `ftp_nlist()` gives you a list of all entries belonging to a given path, I thought that's the way to go. Is there a better method?

Comment: So you want to display a directory listing and additional information? Then you might consider using [`ftp_rawlist()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php), which basicly returns the output of `ls -al` from the current directory on the server. But note that the output may change depending on which OS or FTP server software the server uses. Someone on PHP.net implemented such a method already: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php#108501

Comment: I already implemented a solution using a combination of `mb_substr($item, 0, 1)` for file/directory detection and `$tmp = explode(" ", $item)` and `end($tmp)` for link retrieval, but your link points to a much more developed and correct implementation. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this comment on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php#77007. `ftp_size($ftp_connect, $filename) == -1` is used to check whether it is a directory or a file

Comment: Thanks for the directions, although the last function seems to be server-dependent and my intention is for any client to be able to provide his/her own FTP server addresses (it's a file/document manager what I'm building), so something working for vsftpd but not for proftpd wouldn't be good :P

Comment: Out of curiousity, why build somthing like this yourself instead of using something like [Flysytem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem)?

Comment: It's been quite some time since I posted this and, to be honest, I ended implementing Flysystem as my file abstraction layer :P

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested, here's a follow up to MarcDefiant's comment about using `ftp_rawlist()`. It's fast if you're already using it for getting the file list as well. Here's a snippet from the `filebrowser.php` in my [GitHub filebrowser project](https://github.com/mircerlancerous/FileBrowser). It's certainly not on the same level as [Flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) but I enjoyed working on it :).

```
public function isDir($path,$contents=NULL){
    $name = getPathName($path);
    if($contents === NULL){
        $path = getItemPath($path);
        $contents = $this->scandir($path);
    }
    foreach($contents as $content => $data){
        if($content == $name){
            if($data['type'] == 'directory'){
                return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

public function scandir($path=NULL){
    if($path === NULL){
        $path = $this->Path;
    }
    if(!$path){
        $path = ".";
    }
    if(is_array($children = @ftp_rawlist($this->conn_id, $path))){
        $items = array();

        foreach($children as $name => $child){
            if(!$name){
                continue;
            }
            $chunks = preg_split("/\s+/", $child);
            list($item['rights'], $item['number'], $item['user'], $item['group'], $item['size'], $item['month'], $item['day'], $item['time']) = $chunks;
            $item['type'] = $chunks[0]{0} === 'd' ? 'directory' : 'file';
            array_splice($chunks, 0, 8);
            $items[implode(" ", $chunks)] = $item;
        }

        return $items;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

function getPathName($path){
    return substr($path,strrpos("/".$path,"/"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you OffTheBricks.
Just a little improvment in your code : I replace `$chunks = preg_split( '/\s+/', $child );` by `$chunks = preg_split( '/\s+/', $child, 9 );` and
`array_splice($chunks, 0, 8); $items[implode(" ", $chunks)] = $item;`
by `$name = array_pop( $chunks ); $items[$name] = $item;` because I have some files with several consecutives spaces that was lost by the use of /s+ and implode( " "… ).